# How to retry BatchWrites in DynamoDB and Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a function to do a BatchWrite to DynamoDB using the Python SDK.

```
def do_batch_write(write_list)
    while True:
        with table_name.do_batch_write() as batch:
            for write in write_list:
                batch.put_item(write)

            if (all writes passed):
                 break
            else:
                retry unprocessed writes
```

I know that DDB can fail to do some operations and so you need to check for unprocessed writes and retry them, butI couldn't find an example with the newest Python SDK showing how to find the unprocessed writes. Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the docs? https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item

you would need to inspect UnprocessedItems from the response and from the looks of it you can just feed those into a new **batch_write_item** (i.e. keep looking at the response while you have unprocessed items and keep feeding them into new batch writes requests until you've written everything)

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm unsure how to look through the response for the unprocessed writes.